# Dynamically added ng-click not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented popup / modal window in mobile browser using angular js.

I have used **modal** directive for this which is given in angular js with bootstrap site.

I have kept all the **content of popup** in a variable and while opening popup, I am passing that variable to in element to following function:

```
$scope.open = function (size, element) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
          template : element,
          size: size
        });
    };
```

I have also added a ng-click event in that **content of popup** which is stored in the variable.

But that ng-click function is not working.

Please give me some solution.

Comment: You need to include all of the relevant code. I only see a small bit of the code you mention in your question.

Comment: better create a plunk.

Comment: I want to close window on click of an element present in window.

Comment: please find code at: http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8BvvxZByioxrb1cyr1J?p=preview

Comment: Is your `template` a html code?

Comment: its done............i have added a function inside ModalInstanceCtrl to close this popup

Comment: yes, the template is HTML code

Answer (score 1):

To close that modal window all you need to do is call the same code what is written for cancel or simply call cancel only,from your template.

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
```

This is the way you can close your window I edited your plunker and now its working I just called cancel method from template. Here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xkycWER84ofroL9XtTPu?p=preview)